# Quaternion representation or examples?

Tags: c++, opengl, math, 3d, quaternions

I'm studying 3D rendering with OpenGL, and Quaternions as used to describe rotation have me a bit stuck.

From what I've read so far, they are represented by no more than 4 numbers.  What these 4 numbers are however, has me completely stumped.  I've seen quaternions to be represented with a scalar (usually 1) then `i, k, j`, sometimes with `a, b, c, d`, sometimes mixed with both, then sometimes represented with `w, x, y, z`.

Do they represent different aspects of a Quaternion, or are they simply different letters for the same value?  Were I to roll a Quaternion class, what 4 data members would I use of these?  Do quaternions use more than 4 variables, but certain variables go ignored because 3D graphics uses a simplified version of actual quaternions appearing in math?

I think I could come to a far better understanding if I seen an implementation, even psuedo code, of quaternions in action.  My brain shuts down the moment mathematical notation appears, unfortunately...  If someone suggested an open source library that has clearly written quaternions I could learn from, regardless of language, it would be a tremendous help!

Comment: A quaternion does NOT represent a rotation. A unit quaternion does though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OGRE (Open Graphics Rendering Engine) has a good page at (mainly targeting developers):

http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/Quaternion+and+Rotation+Primer

And as OGRE is open source, you can also browse the source at:

http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/api/1.9/class_ogre_1_1_quaternion.html

Comment: Looking through the documentation alone has been immensely helpful.  Finally found my foothold in this math mountain, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In the following, we are talking about *unit* quaternions only.

**"From what I've read so far, they are represented by no more than 4 numbers."**
A quaternion is represented by exactly 4 values: (x,y,z,w)

**"What these 4 numbers are however, has me completely stumped."** 
in a quaternion, you have one scalar value (usually w), and an imaginary vector (usually x, y, z). You have only ONE unit quaternion with a scalar value of 1: it is the identity quaternion (0,0,0,1).

**"Do quaternions use more than 4 variables."**
No, quaternions are 4 dimensional exactly.

**"but certain variables go ignored because 3D graphics uses a simplified version of actual quaternions appearing in math?"**
Remember that your quaternion is unit. So if you have the first 3 components, you can deduce the last one.

If you want to understand using unit quaternions for 3D rotations, I suggest you read this:

[**Quaternions**, *by Ken Shoemake*](http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~vbz/resources/quatut.pdf)

The most important part is:
[image]

Then, you can read the following to understand why unit quaternions are not always the best representation for 3D rotations:

[**Practical Parameterization of Rotations Using the Exponential Map.**,  *by F. Sebastian Grassia.  Journal of Graphics Tools, 3(3):29-48, 1998*](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/user/spiff/www/moedit99/expmap.pdf)

Comment: Can you really deduce the last one? You'd also need to figure out the sign, no? Hyperhemisphere might be enough to encode rotations though.

Comment: q and -q represent the same rotation. So if you restrict yourself to only use positive quaternions, you should be able to deduce the last component.

Comment: The identity quaternion (representing no rotation) has scalar value 1. This occurs quite frequently.

Comment: @homar: this is the only quaternion with a scalar value of 1. This is what I meant. I edited my answer to be more precise. Thanks for pointing out the confusion!

Answer (score 1):

Quaternions are always 4 numbers that you can call whatever, the order however is important.

The i, j, k is the usually the imaginary representation `quat = 0.5i+0.1j+0.2k+0.8` with `i^2=j^2=k^2=i*j*k=-1` this is an expansion on the normal imaginary numbers (the `a+bi` numbers).

the x, y, z, w representation is just 4 numbers taking the example above means `x=0.5, y=0.1, z=0.2, w=0.8`

To get the rotation from it you can transform it into the axis angle representation by taking the normalized `x, z, y` as the axis and `2*acos(w)` as the angle. However it is more efficient to transform directly to the rotation matrix.

Comment: Quaternion are meant to be used directly as they provide a nice algebra for rotation computation. They are not meant to be converted before being used I believe.